# Resolve Ion cube "cannot be decoded by this version of the ionCube Loader" error - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation, ioncube

I have created a plugin in WordPress and then, I've encrypted this using IonCube 11.0.1 and after I run this plugin in my website, I received This error (**my PHP version is 7.4 and the Ioncube version that is installed on my server is 11.0.1**):

`Fatal error: The file /home/bestelement/public_html/wp-content/plugins/best-element/best-element-codes.php encoded as type [1/74] cannot be decoded by this version of the ionCube Loader. in Unknown on line 0`

Do You know how can I resolve this?

Comment: I think its time to double check which version you encoded with and which version is running on the server

Comment: I guess the interesting and painful reality is newer Ioncube can't read older Ioncube and you have to update en mass.

Answer (score 4):

This can be caused by one of these:

1- ionCube loader version mismatch between your plugin and your web server.

2- PHP version of web server too old or too new.

Assuming that your web server probably uses the latest version of ionCube, you must check your ionCube version on your local machine and check if they match. if this does not help then change PHP version (in most cases downgrade will do the magic) on your web server (or ask your hosting to do so) and find out what PHP version suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I was seting up the wordpress in another place (localhost) with different php version (and so different ionCube version) and I saw this error.

So try to install exact php version of the first place (and related ionCube version)